# What can Android decide to throw out if it needs more memory?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

We are developing an app that needs a foreground service to collect data. I am trying to understand how Android deals with the process and it's activities, if it is bound to a foreground service.

What can Android decide to throw out if it needs more memory? The entire process or just the activities? What is expected behavior?

Follow up question: what events should we be listening to, to make sure we are signaled when this happens? Activity.onDestroy? Is it guaranteed to be fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The entire process or just the activities?

Android terminates processes. *You* can get rid of activities yourself (e.g., call `finish()`), and when they get garbage-collected, Android can return some of your heap space to the system. However, Android does not proactively get rid of individual components this way -- it's the entire process or nothing.

> Follow up question: what events should we be listening to, to make sure we are signaled when this happens?

Nothing is called when your process is terminated.

Comment: So there is no way to know when to save state of process before it is killed?

Comment: @Sten: Correct. Save the state when the state changes.

Answer (score 2):

Android will, indeed, terminate your entire process, if it needs memory.

Activities are freed and become candidates for garbage collection after they are destroyed, freeing up space **within** your process.  Freeing space within your process has no affect on the memory available to Android.

Activity.onDestroy is called best-effort.  It is possible for an Activity to be destroyed without its onDestroy method being called.  onPause is guaranteed.

Android assigns each process a priority, a number between -15 and 16, called oom_adj.  The bigger the number, the more likely a process is to be killed.  Only system applications have oom_adj < 0.  The currently visible app has an oom_adj of 0.  A process with no UI, but a running service will be in the 4-5 area.  A process that is not visible and that has no running service will have a higher oom_adj, and a process that is not in the back-stack will have the highest value.

Each device has a compiled-in table, part of the Android system, that associates oom_adj values with low memory conditions.  This table says, for instance, that if Android gets down to its last 8 M of memory, it should kill any process with an oom_adj of, say, 12 or higher.  As the memory situation gets more dire, Android is allowed to kill processes with lower and lower oom_adj.

When Android kills your process, because it needs memory, it does so with the equivalent of kill -9.

Comment: dammit!  pipped by commonsware again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The process that hosts the Android components will be killed if system consider it using too much memory.

However, since your are using a foreground service, Android will try hard to not kill you process until the memory resource is extremely low. For you activities, you should overwrite the [onSavedInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save your data in case your activity is killed in this scenario.

Also, in order to keep your process being killed by system to reclaim resource, you should keep your memory footprint as small as possible. You can separate your service and the activity components in two processes, because the activity, along with its UI resource, is usually taking much memory than the service. By hosting the activity components in a separate process can protected your service from killed along with the activities.